# RedmineでApplicationHelperの既存のメソッドを書き換えるには？

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, redmine

### やりたいこと

Redmineのプラグインを作成しています.
RedmineのApplicationHelperにはlink_to_projectというメソッドがあり、これを書き換えたいのですが、うまくいきません.

### 環境

- Redmine 3.0.1
- Rails 4.2.1
- Ruby 2.1.5p273

### やったこと

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugin_Internalsを参考に

lib/action_helper_patch.rb

```
require 'application_helper'

module ApplicationHelperPatch
  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)

    base.class_eval do
      unloadable
      alias_method_chain :link_to_project, :project_owner
    end
  end


  module InstanceMethods
    def say_hello
      'say Hello'
    end
    def link_to_project_with_project_owner(project, options={}, html_options = nil)
      if project.archived?
        h(project.name)
      else
        link_to 'hello',
          project_url(project, {:only_path => true}.merge(options)),
          html_options
      end
    end
  end

end


ApplicationHelper.send(:include, ApplicationHelperPatch)
```

init.rbに次の１行を加えました.

```
require_dependency 'application_helper_patch'
```

### 試したこと

自作のプラグインのViewで次のヘルパーを試してみましたが、link_to_projectだけ、思ったとおりに'hello'と表示されず、もとのプロジェクト名が表示されてしまいます.(もちろんproject.archived?はfalseなものもです.)

- say_hello 'say_hello'と表示されました.
- link_to_project_with_project_owner 'hello'というリンクが表示されました.
- link_to_project プロジェクト名が表示されます.

また、Redmineで使っているlink_to_projectもそのままで書き換えられていません.

### 質問

alias_method_chainの使い方をどこかで間違えているのでしょうか？
また、もとのlink_to_projctを書き換えるにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### prependを使う

alias_method_chainではなくprependを使うことで一応目的を達成できました.
http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/method/Module/i/prepend.html

```
require 'application_helper'

module ApplicationHelperPatch
  def say_hello
    'say Hello'
  end
  def link_to_project(project, options={}, html_options = nil)
    if project.archived?
      h(project.name)
    else
      link_to 'hello',
        project_url(project, {:only_path => true}.merge(options)),
        html_options
    end
  end
end

module ApplicationHelper
  prepend ApplicationHelperPatch
end
```